# How do I force this function to always return six character hex color codes?

Tags: javascript, hex

This code is supposed to provide contrasting fg and bg color codes, However there's a bug:

```js
function randomColorPair() {
  const bg = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  let fg = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  while (Math.abs(parseInt(bg.substring(1), 16) - parseInt(fg.substring(1), 16)) < 0x777777) {
    fg = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  }
  return [bg, fg];
}

console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
console.log(randomColorPair());
```

So this function works great, except occassionaly either the bg or fg will only be 4 or 5 characters. Something buggy but it needs to always be six characters for a hex color code.

Comment: See [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](/a/1267338/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Pad the left of the string resulting from `.toString(16)` with 0s if needed. Put it into a function for reusability.

```js
const randomColor = () => (
  '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16).padStart(0, 6)
);
function randomColorPair() {
  const bg = randomColor();
  let fg = randomColor();
  
  while (Math.abs(parseInt(bg.substring(1), 16) - parseInt(fg.substring(1), 16)) < 0x777777) {
    fg = randomColor();
  }

  return [bg, fg];
}
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(randomColorPair());
}
```